# What's wrong with my HDD after long storage?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

Six years ago I bought an external WD HDD. I ran all the tests (back then) that WD's program, "data life guard" had to offer and everything turned out fine.

After making sure everything is ok, I stored my data. Then, I kept it in a dry place, and without the possiblity of any mechanical damage. I also made sure that it was sealed properly from air moisture using cling film and plastic bags, well, I did the best I can.

The only time the drive was ever used was in the beginning, during these tests, and while storing the data on it. So practically it was kept in near "new" condition.

Recently, I connected the drive again to access the data. Now, the first time I connected it, I saw the drive in Computer. I tried to access it and typed the password in the prompt (it was password protected via its own built in software), and then this clicking sound started to come out, and indicator light keeps going on and off on the drive. At the same time, I can't access the data.
I disconnected the drive, plugged it back in for a second time, clicking is the same, but now, it happens on its own plus, it doesn't even appear in Computer!

This has been the situation since then. Everytime I connect it, nothing but the clicking sound, and USB connected sound comes from the computer but, nothing else. Sometimes, at first, it appeared as an unrecognized USB device but now, nothing at all. I tried moving the USB cable around to see if it's properly connected, that's when this horrifying beeping sound briefly came out of the drive. I never tried that again though!

I tried even giving it gentle hits (when it's disconnected of course) on the side with my hands, perhaps the arms inside are stuck but, when connected again, it's nothing but the same. Now, all I'm left with is the clicking sound and nothing on the computer side to show.

It's worth mentioning that, when I touch the drive while connected, I can feel it spinning.

My bet is, perhaps the electric board is faulty from the long "slumber". I'm not sure in fact, I'm no expert, which is why I'm here.

Update: When I keep it connected for a while, an empty CD drive icon appears in Computer, and in notifications area a USB device appears.

What do you believe is the issue with my drive?

Comment: *"it was sealed properly from air moisture using cling film and plastic bags"* -- You need to store it with a desiccant.    *"So practically it was kept in near "new" condition."* -- Apparently you have the mistaken impression that new is good.  Actually new means unproven and not reliable.  If you didn't perform an extended break-in (aka burn-in) test, then the device could be susceptible to [infantile failure](https://www.sweetwater.com/insync/infantile-failure-k-infant-failure-mode/).

Comment: It has been used for several days (tests and copying) so that rules out infantile failure. When I said near new condition I meant compared to a typical HDD lifetime. So based on your answer is the problem electric (the board)? It's important that I know in order to know which direction I will take for maintainance.

Comment: You need to run a S.M.A.R.T test on it. _(clicking being heard isn't the heads being stuck, it occurs when the heads reach the far end of the platters and are reset.)_ Boot an Ubuntu install USB → Try Ubuntu → Open a terminal via `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` → `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install smartmontools` → Use `ls /dev | grep sd` or `dmesg` to get the correct drive _(e.g. `sdc`)_ → `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc` _(Review the values, then scroll down and see if any hardware errors are listed)_ → `sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sdc && sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc` →  `sudo smartctl -t long /dev/sdc`

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Long S.M.A.R.T tests take hours to complete, so to check progress: `smartctl -a /dev/sdc | grep progress`. It sounds like the HDD lost it's partition table, which can be restored via [`TestDisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) - this could have occurred by either accidentally placing the drive next to something with a magnetic field that affected the sectors containing the partition table; it could also be natural magnetic field degradation of the platters  _(you'll need to look up this spec via drive's model number)_.

Comment: @JW0914 The USB device doesn't recognize the drive altogether, not just the partitions. No HDD utilities software I have, recognized the drive, this includes data life guard, HD Sentinel, HD tune, etc... The SMART report as well isn't available! I don't know, but this seems to me like an ATA issue. If the partition table is not found, then it will appear to the computer as an uninitialized disk. For some reason, the surface of the disk is unreachable.

Comment: Please bear in mind, that this HDD has its own, mounting software/driver that usually appears when its connected, as a CD drive in computer. Now, this CD Drive is empty, and the software is not there. This software offers password protection to the entire drive. This appeared only once in the beginning, but now it doesnt any more. I typed the password when I connected the first time, and this clicking sound appeared. Now, even this software/driver isn't there anymore. And the clicking happens on its own, and immediately after connection.

Comment: The click sound could be a head crash, and if so professional data recovery which will cost hundreds of dollars.  This is why a second backup drive is so important.

Comment: @user1232949 It's far more likely there's an issue with the external enclosure's PCB than with the HDD... Look up how to open your external's case on Google or YouTube, remove the HDD from the enclosure and directly connect it to the PC

Comment: @Jw0914 Unfortunately, the USB connection is part of the HDD. The enclosure is just a plastic case. This is it here: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2GGTQF6oE3E

Comment: @cybernard The HDD had been stationary where I kept it. If it's a head crash, what might have caused it? And how to be sure?

Comment: @user1232949 Unless it experienced significant g-forces, hardware damage seems improbable since the heads remain parked on their plastic ramp when power is removed from the HDD. EMF exposure, or platter magnetic degredation seems more plausible. Have you tried a different, known-good USB3 cable?

Comment: @JW0914 I haven't tried a different cable, no. I will look into that despite the fact that the cable also was kept in great condition with the HDD. I even covered the endings (sockets) with cling film to defend against rust. About the magnetic exposure, I did keep this HDD on top of another 3.5" HDD. Could the magnetic field from the motor of that other drive seep through both metal cases of the drives and affected the platters?

Comment: @JW0914 To your point about physical damage to the heads. When this HDD was connected and working many years ago, I usually heard this 1 click when it was not doing something for a while. When I did my research back then, I learned that this was a protective measure to protect the heads/platters from any sudden physical shocks while it was connected. With that said, I assume that the first time I connected this drive after that long wait, the heads/arms were in parking position.

Comment: *"... that rules out infantile failure"* -- No, you don't have definitive evidence of that.  It's a probability issue based on power-on-hours, not calendar days.   *"... sealed properly ... using cling film"* -- That's not a *"proper seal"* for electronic components. Cling film/wrap uses static electricity, and its use near electronics increases the chances for damage by **ESD**.